# Bigquery - Text clustering

Tags: cloud, cluster-analysis, data-mining, google-bigquery, k-means

Does anyone knows who to run text clustering over a google's bigquery table ? I'd tried to use nltk over some small dataset (2k rows, single column) but it seems to take forever (99% CPU on a quadcore, 8GB machine, Linux).

Thanks !

Comment: nltk.what?  99% CPU for 1 msec, 5msec, several hours?  Your question is vastly underspecified (and I'm surprised it attracted an answer)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already using Google-Cloud tools, it's worth looking into [Google Prediction API](https://developers.google.com/prediction/). I have not used it personally, but I've heard good things about the size of the datasets it can handle.

Since you mentioned a Python library -- another option (which might also be limited by size of the dataset), is to use PyData tools which includes Pandas for importing data (look at `Pandas.io.read_bq`) and the Scikit-learn package to run your clustering algorithms. There's quite a bit of optimization for speed built-in.